# Xamarin android: Consuming C# library from Java

Tags: android, xamarin

Is it possible to create a library written in C# and use it from an Android application written in Java?

Why would anybody want it? Simple - when having existing apps, it is hard to convince people to rewrite them in Xamarin. But if you start small, with creating some shared reusable parts, the adoption is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You can consume native Android (Java) libraries from Xamarin C# code by writing bindings for them, but they are one way only.  You cannot consume C# libraries from native Android.